# How to translate PHP array identifier into a string that can be used in MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This question probably has a simple solution. Here's what I am doing:

I am dynamically creating checkbox inputs with a PHP loop.

```
<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"current\" name=\"User[$row[0]]\" value=\"1\" ></td>
```

This snippet, `name=\"User[$row[0]]\"`, is part of an array that is passed via post upon submission. Rather than using `User[]`, I define the associative array by using `$row[0]`. `$row[0]` allows me to use a unique identifier that is really a UserId - it is guaranteed to be unique. The value of an instance of a submitted array is either 1 or 0 (true or false). This is a result of print_r(said array):

```
Array ( [1] => 1 
        [12] => 0
        [31] => 1 
        [4] => 1 )
```

What I need to do is use the User Id (which happens to be the identifier of a component of the array, i.e. 1, 12, 31...) in a SQL query. For example.

```
UPDATE...WHERE UserId = array identifier
```

At the same time, I need to use the value of that component (0 or 1) in that same query.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you process your array, use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($results as $key => $value)
{
    $sql .= "UPDATE...WHERE UserId = $key;";
}
```

This lets you not only use the value of each array element, but also its key.  See the php manual for more on [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Thanks! I now know yet another use for this function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop with `key=>value` pair

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET column = $val WHERE UserId = $key";
}
```